# Mysql Where clause with calendar week and for loop

Tags: mysql, loops, calendar, where-clause

i need a WHERE Clause for MYSQL to select in a Table with a timestamp a calendar week from Monday to Sunday.

For example i am in calendar week 2 of 2016 on Wednesday and i need a WHERE Clause to get the data BETWEEN Monday and Sunday von calendar week 1 of 2016. 
I the next step i need an integer which i can count up to get the calendar week 52 of 2015 from Monday to Sunday and calendar week 51 in the next step.

Something like a For-Loop to get for example 10 different SQL Queries from the actual week back to the past.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Cu kami

Comment: Can someone help me with this? -- it should be *Can someone code for me with this?*.. -- this not freelancer site.. first try some code and then come here for help

Comment: Can you post your DB schema/Any SQL you have tested? This will help others when trying to determine the solution.

Comment: Hi, i am sorry i will try to show you my example: SELECT MIN(wert) as minkwlges , MAX(wert) as maxkwlges, AVG(wert) as mitkwlges, DATE_FORMAT( timestamp, '%d' ) AS dateday, DATE_FORMAT( timestamp, '%a' ) AS datewk, MIN(Volumen) as first_val, MAX(Volumen) as last_val FROM `meter` WHERE timestamp > DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL $value DAY ) )  ORDER BY `dateday` ASC For this is $value like 1,7,14,.... Thanks a lot